# Pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, pip, python-3.11

Я проверил много способов, ничего не помогает. Мне хочется плакать :(

Версии:
Python 3.11.0
pip 22.3
Debian 11

[image: error]

```
(venvBot) admin@ip-172-31-36-107:~/answerBot$ pip install -r requirements.txt
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/aiogram/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/aiogram/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/aiogram/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiogram==2.23.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiogram==2.23.1
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: С новыми версиями часто проблемы, попробуйте постарее, например 3.10.9.

Answer (score 0):

У меня аналогичная проблема исправилась, когда я в переменне среды(и в верхнее окно и в нижнее) прописал несколько папок интерпритатора:

~\Anaconda\Library\bin
~\Anaconda\Lib
~\Anaconda\Scripts
~\Anaconda

И в питоне в Settings\tools\terminal\shell path  я прописал cmd.exe.

И перед этим установил SSl с этого сайта https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Не знаю, что именно помогло, но больше ошибок при установке пакетов нет.

Comment: У меня debian!!